# Is there a way to test for a specific sql exception type in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When deleting a record from the database, occasionally I will run into a reference constraint exception.

Here are the exception details.  Is it possible to display a message to the user when the exception is specifically related to a foreign key constraint error?

I can look at the exception error string and test for the existence of a word, but I wasn't sure if there is a better way to check for a specific SQL error.

Thanks
Kevin

```
Message: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Customers_PaymentTerms". The conflict occurred in database "kd", table "dbo.Customers", column 'CstPtmID'.
The statement has been terminated.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
TargetSite: Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean)
StackTrace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible to display a message to the user when the exception is
>   specifically related to a foreign key constraint error?

Yes, you could check the [`Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) of the SqlException:

```
try
{
    // do your database query
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == .....)
    {
        // Can't remember from the top of my head the exact error code 
        // that is triggered in this situation. Just check it.
    }
}
```

---

As explained in the comments section, it is better to check the [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx) array because there might be multiple errors related to a single SQL query.

Comment: You need to check for the entire [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx) array because a single batch (SQL request) can return multiple errors.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer to include this valuable information.

Comment: Here's a list of error codes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603(SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look under SqlException

```
catch(SqlException se)
{
    if(se.Number == x)
    {
        //Show message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx) collection to display errors:

```
public static void ShowSqlException(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString = "EXECUTE NonExistantStoredProcedure";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            DisplaySqlErrors(ex);
        }
    }
}

private static void DisplaySqlErrors(SqlException exception)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < exception.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index #" + i + "\n" +
            "Error: " + exception.Errors[i].ToString() + "\n") +
            "Number: " + exception.Errors[i].Number.ToString() + "\n");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```